# Facebook gifting send plural form of object type in Unity3d

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am sending apprequest to send "Gift" to friends.

Code which i am using to send gift is as below :

```
FB.AppRequest (Send_Gift_Message, OGActionType.SEND, GIFT_10_COINS, toFriends, null, "Send Gift", delegate(IAppRequestResult result) {
                
            });
```

This is sending gift request perfectly but i just want to change message which is shown while sending gift.

I am attaching image which shows message :

[image]

I want to change "sent you a coin:". I want to use **"sent you coins:"**.

Is it possible to change ?

If it is possible then plaese guide me steps.

Thanks.

Comment: No, that is not possible AFAIK. You can specify whether “a” or “an” is used, and what the plural form of your object name is (both in app dashboard, in your OG object properties), and you can edit the different phrases used as well, in the story configuration – but as long as you publish a single action on an object, it will still show the singular form of the object name. (And naming your object with the plural form to begin with is not allowed by Facebook, they’ll reject that in review.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe.